# Hide or remove a part of a border in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm wondering how to remove a little part of a border inside a popup. I marked the part I want to remove with a red arrow in the picture.
Thanks for your help.

Here is the Xaml code

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder"/>
        <DockPanel>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="0" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">
            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MenuBorderColorBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Margin="1,0" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuBorderColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{StaticResource MenuBorderColorBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#848589"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

[image: Remove a part of the border]

Comment: What style do you use for the menu on screenshot? Is that the default for VS2012?

Comment: Hi i did my own style to look like the menus in visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved this with an extra border above the part i wanted to hide. And under the HighLight Trigger i setted the width of my new border so it can match the headers width.

Here is the code:

```
    <Style x:Key="MetroMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="Separator">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuBorderColorBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command"
                        Value="{Binding Command}" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <!--Border 1-->
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0" MinWidth="17" Width="Auto" 
                                                      SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Icon" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                  ContentSource="Icon"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                  x:Name="HeaderHost" RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                                  ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Margin="8,1,8,1" x:Name="IGTHost" 
                                                  ContentSource="InputGestureText" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="3" Margin="4,0,6,0" x:Name="ArrowPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                       Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="-1" x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Focusable="false"
                                       PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
                                       AllowsTransparency="True">
                                    <Grid Margin="0,0,5,5">
                                        <!--Border 2-->
                                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" 
                                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuBorderColorBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}" 
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <Grid x:Name="SubMenu" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Margin="2">
                                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" 
                                                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Color="Black"/>
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                        </Border>
                                        <!--Border 3-->
                                        <Border Margin="1,0,0,0" x:Name="TransitionBorder" Width="0" Height="2" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                Background="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                                                BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0,6,2"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="Placement" Value="Bottom"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="SubMenuBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="SubMenu" Property="Margin" Value="2,3,2,2"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="TransitionBorder" Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Grid}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0,6,2"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,0,3"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,0,3"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuMouseOverColorBrush}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MenuOpenBackgroundColorBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource MenuBorderColorBrush}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanelPath" Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundColorBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sounds great, @Tan! Would you mind to post some xaml for other readers so that they could use your solution as well?

Comment: To anyone who happens upon this answer and is having trouble finding what is actually "removing" the border.  Look at the "TransitionBorder" in the template.  It has 0 width normally, but in a trigger it is set to the width of the "Grid" element.  So it essentially covers up the small portion of the popup border that intersects with the menu item.  
I had my templates set up a little differently, and so I have the xaml for setting the width in a trigger for when the popup IsOpen property is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do it simple way but without success, sorry. This is tricky mostly because in WPF menu control implemented with pop-up control under the hood, which in turn is kind of individual top-most window and you can't just change it's Canvas.ZIndex to negative value and draw top-level menu element over it so that result overlap could hide the line you want to remove.

One possible (and feasible, imho) way to eliminate the line you marked on image could be some kind of additional top-level rectangle in the menu item control template that will just hide the left part of the top border over menu popup. This rectangle, however, will need to get the exact width of top-level menu item (via element binding, probably) so that it could hide exact amount of line you marked on image.

Nevertheless this possible solution sounds a bit over complicated to me and if possible I would instead prefer radically change the way the menu is implemented, for example - with using tab control to hold all lists of child menu items and the tabs headers will form the top-level menus or something like that. This way you will at least have more control over UI  layout and add some nice animation for opening and closing menu will be easy.

Comment: Hey! I solved it with adding an extra border that blocks the part i wanted to hide. Then in the highlight trigger i setted the width of the border.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ControlTemplate for  MenuItem to custom this style.

Comment: Please delete Microsoft theme for popup

Like this:
 <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="0" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3" >
                <Border x:Name="Shdw" Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" BorderBrush="#BF000000" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,4,4,4"><Border.Effect><DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="4" Color="#7F1E1E1E"/></Border.Effect>
</Border>

Comment: You should edit your answer instead of using comments. Comments are meant for discussion and cannot be formatted.

Comment: Tried yours and it didnt remove the top left part of the border.What is the trick ? is it to make an extra rectangle above that part i want to hide ?

Answer (score 0):

Tan,
I use below xaml code in TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey or SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey to custom popup border:

```
          <Grid
                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            MinWidth="14"
                            Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            Width="4" />
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            Width="37" />
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup"
                            Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            Width="17" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="Icon"
                        ContentSource="Icon"
                        Margin="1"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Border
                        x:Name="GlyphPanel"
                        BorderBrush="#CDD3E6"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Background="#E6EFF4"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Height="22"
                        Margin="1"
                        Visibility="Hidden"
                        Width="Auto">
                        <Path
                            x:Name="Glyph"
                            Data="{DynamicResource Checkmark}"
                            Fill="#0C12A1"
                            FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                            Height="11"
                            Width="9" />
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="-2,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        ContentSource="Header"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="4"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Path
                        Grid.Column="5"
                        Data="{DynamicResource Checkmark}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>

                <Popup
                    x:Name="PART_Popup"
                    AllowsTransparency="true"
                    Focusable="false"
                    IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
                    Placement="Right"
                    >
                    <Border
                        x:Name="Shdw"
                        Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                        BorderBrush="#BF000000"
                        BorderThickness="4"
                        CornerRadius="0">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect
                                ShadowDepth="0"
                                BlurRadius="4"
                                Color="#7F1E1E1E" />
                        </Border.Effect>

                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer"
                            CanContentScroll="true"
                            Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid
                                RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <ItemsPresenter
                                    x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                    Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger
                    Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation"
                    Value="true">
                    <Setter
                        Property="PopupAnimation"
                        TargetName="PART_Popup"
                        Value="None" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="Icon"
                    Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="Icon"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="IsChecked"
                    Value="true">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="Icon"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger
                    Property="HasDropShadow"
                    SourceName="PART_Popup"
                    Value="true">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Margin"
                        TargetName="Shdw"
                        Value="0,0,5,5" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger
                    Property="IsEnabled"
                    Value="false">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Foreground"
                        Value="#FF9A9A9A" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Background"
                        TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Value="#EEE9E9" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="BorderBrush"
                        TargetName="GlyphPanel"
                        Value="#DBD6D6" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Fill"
                        TargetName="Glyph"
                        Value="#848589" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

screensnap like this:
[image]@

Answer (score 0):

Use `BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"` same as Padding or Margin. My sample was `BorderThickness="2,2,0,2"` to remove the right border. Remember the order is 'Left', 'Top', 'Right', 'Bottom'.