# Remove portion of submenu border

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

How can I remove the segment of a submenu border that touches the parent menu? Referring to the image below, what I currently have is on the left and what I want is on the right.

[image]

Comment: Since I don't have time at the moment to go test I'll just comment, but if I remember right you should just be able to go look at the `{x:Type MenuItem}` in the [ControlTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and there's a `Border` in there in there with a hard set `BorderThickness="1"` that you can just change to ="1,0,1,1"

Comment: I already have that set, actually; the segment I want to remove is actually part of the Popup template.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083925/hide-or-remove-a-part-of-a-border-in-wpf

Comment: Looks like it's the same problem, but I can't for the life of me find the relevant part of those ~150 lines of XAML.

Comment: (Actually, pasting in his XAML and defining the missing resources just causes the app to crash on startup for me.)

Comment: If you want to share the xaml I'll show you what to do. I just didn't recall the structure since I haven't wpf in awhile but it shouldn't be too much of a chore, xaml is cake.